# There's Reverse Accessor Error occuring. What is it and how do I solve it?

Tags: django, postgresql

```
 class Feedback(models.Model):
        user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='feedback',)

        feedback = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

I used related_name but it didn't work

[image: [iamge]

Comment: Can you paste the reset model file?

Comment: you need to define your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py

Comment: @NalinDobhal, thnks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-user-model)

example:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```